# JPA custom native query with unidirectional @OneToMany / JOIN

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, join, one-to-many

I am struggeling with the following setup:

```java
@Entity
public class RankingAward extends AbstractRelationalModel {

    [...] // some fields

    @Column(name = "rank")
    public Integer placement;

    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    public String profession;

    @Column(name = "company_id")
    public Integer companyId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    private Set<AdditionalPlacements> otherPlacements;

    [...] // some more fields
```

```java
@Entity
public static class AdditionalPlacements {

    [...] // in fact just a subset of the above fields
          // ideally fetched through a JOIN

    @Column(name = "rank")
    public Integer placement;

    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    public String profession;

    @Column(name = "company_id")
    public Integer companyId;
}
```

Both Entities have **no** explicit table-mapping, as the table name is derived **during runtime**.
`RankingAward` and `AdditionalPlacement` are in fact the same table.
I am currently trying to fetch data through `entityManager.createNativeQuery()` in the hope that a JOIN should deliver the subset result for `AdditionalPlacement`.
So i am basically doing a JOIN to the table itself and would like to have a result like this:

```json
[
  {
    // all fields of RankingAward
    "companyId": 12345,
    "rank": 1,
    "profession": 3
    "additionalPlacements": [
      {
        // all fields of AdditionalPlacements
        "companyId": 12345,
        "rank": 2,
        "profession": 10
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The custom SQL query looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.`rank`, a.profession_id, a.company_id, 
    a2.id, a2.`rank`, a2.profession_id, a2.company_id, 
FROM awards_for_2022
LEFT JOIN awards_for_2022 a2 on a.company_id = a2.company_id and a2.id != a.id
WHERE a.profession_id = :professionId
ORDER BY a.`rank`;
```

I thought that the JOIN could anyhow be mapped to the `otherPlacements` set, but i am not sure how and what the best solution would be. Should i use JPQL? I think strict JPA annotations can't work as the table name is kind of *dynamic*.

I tried different version of JPA mapping annotations in combination with `@OneToMany`. some resulted in exceptions like `Table 'RankingAward$AdditionalPlacements' doesn't exist`. Before i restructue the database model so that all corresponding tables end up in one table and therefore maybe enable the use of annotations, i wanted to try it via custom SQL.

Edit:

I would like to have this query

```sql
SELECT a.id, a.`rank`, a.profession_id, a.company_id,
       a2.id, a2.`rank`, a2.profession_id, a2.company_id # maybe some group_concat() here?
FROM competitionline.awards_for_2022 a
LEFT JOIN competitionline.awards_for_2022 a2 on a.company_id = a2.company_id and a2.id != a.id
WHERE a.profession_id = 1
order by a.`rank`;
```

with this result:

```sql
+--+----+-------------+----------+----+----+-------------+----------+
|id|rank|profession_id|company_id|id  |rank|profession_id|company_id|
+--+----+-------------+----------+----+----+-------------+----------+
|1 |1   |1            |10344     |4279|7   |38           |10344     |
|1 |1   |1            |10344     |4214|34  |32           |10344     |
|1 |1   |1            |10344     |3310|20  |26           |10344     |
|2 |2   |1            |10541     |null|null|null         |null      |
|3 |3   |1            |12152     |4286|9   |38           |12152     |
+--+----+-------------+----------+----+----+-------------+----------+
```

to end up in an entity of `RankingAward.java` (==`a`) with a list of `AdditionalPlacements.java` (==`a2`).
The shown result says that the company with id `10344` has a ranking placement of `1` in the profession category `1` and 3 other ranking placements (`7`, `34`, `20`) in different profession categories (`38`, `32`, `26`).

Comment: I am also trying to achieve this via `@ElemenCollection`

Comment: I was writing some code to try to answer your question, but a doubt came to mind. In `RankingAward`, the `@OneToMany` mapping has a `@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")`. This means that there is a column `company_id` in `AdditionalPlacements` entity that maps to `RankingAward` entity `id` column. In other words, `company_id` is a foreign key to `RankingAward.id`. That said, I'm having trouble to understand the JOIN clause in the SQL. Shouldn't it be `JOIN awards_for_2022 a2 on a.id = a2.company_id`?

Comment: Ah, no. Semantically this table joins itself via `company_id` to find out which other ranking placements this company has in other professions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

I think there's an inconsistency between the entity mappings and the SQL query. The `@JoinColumn` annotation in the `@OneToMany` mapping on the `RankingAward` entity defines `company_id` on the target entity, `AdditionalPlacements`, as a *foreign key* to itself. In other words, `AdditionalPlacements.company_id` is *foreign key* to `RankingAward.id`. That's the relationship that is defined in that mapping.

But let's put this aside for now. Looking at the table you provided at the end of your answer, the way I see it, admiting both entities map to the same table, there's no way to determine a `RankingAward` from `AdditionalPlacements` entities. I mean, they all share the same `company_id`, but how do you know which row represents a `RankingAward` entity and which rows represent `AdditionalPlacements` entities? Maybe you can use aggregates in your SQL, but I don't think they would work for entity mappings.

A famous example of an entity relating to itself is the employee / manager relationship. But, in this case, the `Employee.managerId` is foreign key to `Employee.id`. Therefore there's a way to determine which is which.

*How about instead of doing this join in the SQL, you do it using Java Collectors?* Option 3 deals with this possibility.

---

### OPTION 1

Basically, the same mappings you provided.

Entities classes:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "awards_for_2022")
public class RankingAward {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(name = "rank")
    Integer placement;
    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    String profession;
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    Integer companyId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    Set<AdditionalPlacements> otherPlacements;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "awards_for_2022")
public class AdditionalPlacements {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(name = "rank")
    Integer placement;
    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    String profession;
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    Integer companyId;

}
```

Setting the `<property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create" />` property in `persistence.xml` prints the following output:

```sql
create table awards_for_2022 (id integer not null, company_id integer, rank integer, profession_id varchar(255), primary key (id));
alter table if exists awards_for_2022 add constraint FK37k8ntxpbbreo0txso10y53bw foreign key (company_id) references awards_for_2022;
```

This means that the persistence provider can relate both entities to the same table. I know you're defining the Entity-Table association dynamically. And as I understand it, your problem isn't there, but in the SQL, right?

So let's load some data for tests:

```sql
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, company_id, rank, profession_id) values (1, null, 1, 'prof1');
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, company_id, rank, profession_id) values (2, 1, 2, 'prof2');
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, company_id, rank, profession_id) values (3, 1, 3, 'prof3');
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, company_id, rank, profession_id) values (4, 2, 4, 'prof4');
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, company_id, rank, profession_id) values (5, 2, 5, 'prof5');
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, company_id, rank, profession_id) values (6, 3, 6, 'prof6');
```

And, finally, a dummy service to execute the query and print the retrieved data:

```java
@Stateless
@Path("")
public class Service {

    private static final Function<RankingAward, JsonObject> RANKINGAWARD2JSON = (RankingAward ra) -> {
        var json = Json.createObjectBuilder()
                .add("id", ra.id)
                .add("rank", ra.placement)
                .add("profession", ra.profession)
                .add("additionalPlacements", ra.otherPlacements.stream()
                        .map(ap -> Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                .add("companyId", ap.companyId)
                                .add("rank", ap.placement)
                                .add("profession", ap.profession)
                                .build())
                        .collect(JsonCollectors.toJsonArray()));

        if (null != ra.companyId) {
            json
                    .add("companyId", ra.companyId);
        }

        return json.build();
    };
    
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @POST
    public void execute(@FormParam("profession") final String prof) {
        var rs1 = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT ra FROM RankingAward ra WHERE ra.profession = :professionId",
                RankingAward.class)
                .setParameter("professionId", prof)
                .getResultStream()
                .map(RANKINGAWARD2JSON)
                .collect(JsonCollectors.toJsonArray());

        System.out.println(rs1);
    }
}
```

The output in `System.out` (calling the service with form parameter `profession=prof1`):

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "rank": 1,
        "profession": "prof1",
        "additionalPlacements": [
            {
                "companyId": 1,
                "rank": 2,
                "profession": "prof2"
            },
            {
                "companyId": 1,
                "rank": 3,
                "profession": "prof3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And this is all the SQL you have to write: `SELECT ra FROM RankingAward ra WHERE ra.profession = :professionId`. As you can see, it isn't necessary to write the JOIN clause. The persistence provider derives the JOIN itself following the mapping on `otherPlacements` field. By the way, the query is in JPQL form.

### OPTION 2

Instead of having a unidirectional relationship from `RankingAward` entity to `AdditionalPlacements` entity, I'd create a bidirectional relationship using a `@ManyToOne` mapping on `AdditionalPlacements` entity.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "awards_for_2022")
public class RankingAward {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(name = "rank")
    Integer placement;
    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    Integer profession;
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    Integer companyId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "rankingAward")
    Set<AdditionalPlacements> otherPlacements;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "awards_for_2022")
public class AdditionalPlacements {

    @Id
    int id;

    @Column(name = "rank")
    Integer placement;
    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    String profession;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
    RankingAward rankingAward;
}
```

Setting the `<property name="jakarta.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action" value="create" />` property in `persistence.xml` prints the same ddl. This shows that despite the mapping changes, the table structure remains the same.

```sql
create table awards_for_2022 (id integer not null, company_id integer, rank integer, profession_id varchar(255), primary key (id));
alter table if exists awards_for_2022 add constraint FK37k8ntxpbbreo0txso10y53bw foreign key (company_id) references awards_for_2022;
```

From this point on, the rest is pretty much the same - actually, only a few minor changes in `RANKINGAWARD2JSON` lambda transformation were required.

---

So why change the relationship mapping? In my opinion, having a `RankingAward` reference in `AdditionalPlacements` helps to understand the relation between these entities. In the first option, the `@JoinColumn` mapping on `RankingAward` entity is defining a column name for the `AdditionalPlacements` entity - which is quite counterintuitive.

### OPTION 3

Instead of grouping different rows and supposedly different entities in the SQL, how about group by them using Java Collectors?

```java
@Entity
public class EntityRecord {

    @Id
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "rank")
    private Integer placement;
    @Column(name = "profession_id")
    private Integer profession;
    @Column(name = "company_id")
    private Integer companyId;

    /* getters, setters and constructors */

}

@Stateless
@Path("")
public class Service {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @POST
    @Produces("application/json")
    public JsonArray execute() {
        /* You can use whichever query you want here, JPQL, native query, etc */
        return em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM EntityRecord e", EntityRecord.class)
                .getResultStream()
                .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                        Collectors.groupingBy(EntityRecord::companyId), (map) -> {
                            return map.entrySet().stream()
                                    .map(entry -> {
                                        return Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                                .add("companyId", entry.getKey())
                                                .add("placements", entry.getValue().stream()
                                                        .map(val -> {
                                                            return Json.createObjectBuilder()
                                                                    .add("id", val.id())
                                                                    .add("profession", val.profession())
                                                                    .add("rank", val.rank())
                                                                    .build();
                                                        })
                                                        .collect(JsonCollectors.toJsonArray()))
                                                .build();
                                    })
                                    .collect(JsonCollectors.toJsonArray());
                        }));
        }
}
```

Populating the database with the following data sample:

```sql
-- the same sample you provided, but before flattening the data
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, rank, profession_id, company_id) values (1, 1, 1, 10344);
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, rank, profession_id, company_id) values (2, 2, 1, 10541);
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, rank, profession_id, company_id) values (3, 3, 1, 12152);
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, rank, profession_id, company_id) values (3310, 20, 26, 10344);
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, rank, profession_id, company_id) values (4214, 34, 32, 10344);
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, rank, profession_id, company_id) values (4279, 7, 38, 10344);
insert into awards_for_2022 (id, rank, profession_id, company_id) values (4286, 9, 38, 12152);
```

Now calling the `Service.execute()` method produces the following json:

```json
[
    {
        "companyId": 12152,
        "placements": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "profession": 1,
                "rank": 3
            },
            {
                "id": 4286,
                "profession": 38,
                "rank": 9
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "companyId": 10344,
        "placements": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "profession": 1,
                "rank": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 3310,
                "profession": 26,
                "rank": 20
            },
            {
                "id": 4214,
                "profession": 32,
                "rank": 34
            },
            {
                "id": 4279,
                "profession": 38,
                "rank": 7
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "companyId": 10541,
        "placements": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "profession": 1,
                "rank": 2
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: hey mauricio, thank you for your effort. unfortunately this won't help as the selected table is derived during runtime. it could be `awards_for_[2018-2022]` :/

Comment: i was hoping that i can use my native SQL query (with a JOIN to the table itself) and then map the result to a given entity (like the one i posted). i bet there is a way to achieve this^^